# .Net Error LINQ - new classname with

Tags: vb.net, linq

Why would VS keep saying to add this?

```
Sub New()
    ' TODO: Complete member initialization 
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the `sampleRecord` object? Could you post the complete LINQ query?

Comment: posted now... its a chunk of a line read from a text file, like i said if i try without the class , its fine

Comment: Day = DayValue    ->   Day=dayValue

Comment: fixed that but not causing the issue,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a constructor that takes parameters, a default, parameterless constructor is not created for you automatically.

Your LINQ statement is not calling your parameterized constructor, it need a parameterless constructor.

Basically, when you code this:

```
Select New CommunityEvent With {.Day = sRecord(0), etc. }
```

What gets generated is this

```
Dim obj As New CommunityEvent()   'Uses parameterless constructor
obj.Day = sRecord(0)
'etc.
```

When you remove the `CommunityEvent With` part, then it doesn't use your class, it creates an anonymous type instead.

Comment: so i should use streamwriter and loop that way ?

Comment: I guess it depends on whether or not you need actual instances of your class.  The code you posted only seems to make use of the .Name property.  Do you use the `query` variable elsewhere?

Comment: i need to take rows using WHERE and store those rows as a list(of CommunityEvent)  , then i need to have a combobox with  name, when a name is selected , the rest of the row should be shown in other textboxs